# Presenting a normalised dataset where previously dated values need to be inherited/included

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, measure, powerbi-datasource

I have a relatively simple dataset (example below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHj9k.png)) where I will request users to update a rating at frequent periods. My intention is to visualize overall change (all items move to a 100% state) over time.

I expect the source dataset to contain minimal data, so I only add rows for specifically updated (new) values. We do not remove previous values, and each process has a unique ID.

I want to visualize this along the lines of the example below [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeOMV.png).

However, when I select a later date, it's taken as literally only values with that entry and shows only the score for the single item (Process5), see [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3i8s.png).

Where do I need to read up in order to understand how to change that request to something along the lines of:

```
select the latest value(s) of each process score
up to the latest date entered
up to and including the user-selected date/period
```

Any pointers/advice/examples would be fantastic!

**PART 2:**
So I investigated some options, and it seems applying some sort of 'measure' is a reasonable direction.

I applied the following measure, but note that it does show the last item for the date selected, but it doesn't 'also' bring in items from an earlier date as part of the same graph source - looking for advice on debugging this to tweak and work out where I can improve.

*Unique ID is a combination of the date (yyyymmdd) and the ID*

*The Date table is just a table with dates in from the earliest to the latest dates presented in the main table (tblProcessSummary)*

```
LatestMainTable = 
MAXX (
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'tblProcessSummary' ),
        [Unique ID] = MAX ( [Unique ID] )
            && [Review Date] >= MIN ( 'Date'[Date] )
            && [Review Date] <= MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )
    ),
    [Review Date]
)
```

Thanks

[image: Example dataset]
[image: Example visualisation]
[image: Current output]